# Invalid model identifier while migrating my data from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, wagtail

I'm trying to migrate my Wagtail application from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL but I'm getting an error saying

> Invalid model identifier: 'wagtailsearch.sqliteftsindexentry'

This is while I type in the command:

> python manage.py loaddata data.json

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 235, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'sqliteftsindexentry'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 181, in _get_model 
    return apps.get_model(model_identifier)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 213, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 237, in get_model
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: App 'wagtailsearch' doesn't have a 'sqliteftsindexentry' model.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\mdrift\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute   
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv 
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute       
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 102, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 163, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
oad_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 70, in Deserializer  
    yield from PythonDeserializer(objects, **options)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 103, in Deserializer
    Model = _get_model(d["model"])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 183, in _get_model 
    raise base.DeserializationError(
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Mdrift_Wagtail\mdrift\data.json': Invalid model identifier: 'wagtailsearch.sqliteftsindexentry'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wagtailsearch.sqliteftsindexentry table is used to store indexed data for searching - this differs between databases, so this table doesn't exist on Postgres. You should exclude it from your `dumpdata` command using the `--exclude=wagtailsearch.sqliteftsindexentry` option - this will then give you a .json dump you can load into Postgres.

Once you've migrated successfully, run `./manage.py update_index` to populate the search index for Postgres.